# List to dictionary conversion

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert the list 
L = ['Name', 'Adam', 'Ben', 'Catlyn', 'Age', '25', '24', '27' ] 
to a dictionary 
D = {'Name': ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Catlyn']. 'Age' : '25', '24', '27' }

Comment: What hinders you to do so? What did you try? Where is your code? What does not work? How do you decide that "Name" and "Age" are keys? How do you decide that the strings with numbers are ages  and the strings w/o numbers are names?

Comment: What did you search on SO and what did you find and why was it not helpfull?  Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

(Just putting in an appearance on SO today.)

- Find the positions of the strings 'Name' and 'Age' within the list `L`.
- Use these positions to slice the list in forming the dictionary.

---

```
>>> L = ['Name', 'Adam', 'Ben', 'Catlyn', 'Age', '25', '24', '27' ]
>>> name_pos = L.index('Name')
>>> age_pos = L.index('Age')
>>> D = {'Name': L[1+name_pos:age_pos], 'Age': L[1+age_pos:]}
>>> D
{'Name': ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Catlyn'], 'Age': ['25', '24', '27']}
```